# windows vista download only part of file

Tags: windows-vista, download

i'm trying to download some files from my web mail. the download is start and every time after the file is about 80% complete, vista telling me that the download is finished 
(and off course, i cant open the file)
what can cause this problam? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your web browser's cache and delete the partially-downloaded file.  Sometimes if the download stalls and you try to download the same file again, you'll end up with the same partial download.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a download manager like [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201) for Firefox. It's fast and lets you resume failed downloads.